# Unusable project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been working on an app for 2 years, 1 month ago I stopped updating it to focus on other things and today I wanted to resume the project. The last time I made changes it was working fine. Today I opened Android Studio and without making changes I tried to run my app on the device that I always use for testing but never compiled, I received "Read time out", Restart Android Studio and now all the classes in the app appear with errors that do not exist (context and type errors: cannot resolve method, cannot find symbol),I have tried using the options:

- Invalidate caches / restart
- Clean project
- Rebuilt project

But the problem continues, I am not attaching code because it is not a programming error, I assume it is from Android Studio... I have no idea what could happen or how to solve it, I will appreciate every answer

Comment: that's why you should always make use of version control and even a build server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting .gradle and .idea folders of the project. Then open the Android Studio and clean and rebuild the project again.

If the problem persist try checking the android dependencies and see which one is creating the problem.

Comment: This fixes my problem, thank you very much